# How can I (if I can) use the git to hold small source-code tests?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a small C++ project out of one source file. It is designated to investigate some C++ features.

I want to store history of this tests. Let's say, there is a beginning version of the `main` function which does not do anything. Then, I changed it in order to investigate some C++ language feature -- let's call it feature A. I want to save its result in the git repository, so that I could return to it in the future. Then, I want start an investigation of the feature B on the basis of the beginning state because the feature B does not, in most cases, relate to the feature A.

I see, that I can do a commit to store results of every test. But I am not sure how can I do it. If I will do this in a linear manner, then every next feature will depend on the previous ones. But, I prefer that they'll depend on the beginning state (commit). If I'll make a dedicated branch for every test, I can get a huge (very "wide") tree.

So, I'll glad to get any answers. Or, maybe, I chose incorrect tool for this task?..

Comment: What problems do you foresee in having a wide tree?

Comment: Probably, in number of branches.

Comment: That's not an answer. What problem do you anticipate if you have, say, 100 branches?

Comment: I need to name every brunch. And, probably, this name will share the commit's message. So, the thing is in elegancy, while it is possible technically.

Comment: That's not an issues for the number of branches. That's an issue of the branch *name*, which is entirely under your control. The branch name isn't *supposed* to be a complete description of the branch's purpose.

Comment: See `git help notes`.

Comment: You can also add to the repository objects that aren't commits on any particular branch; see https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects. Such objects can be tagged, so that you can still access them without having them in the development branch whose code created them.

Answer (score 0):

Ironically, StackOverflow is not very good tool to discuss opinion-based design decision.

But here I would say treat it as a regular project. We do not kill FeatureA, when we start working on FeatureB. We just add FeatureB into the existing project on top of FeatureA.

Here it makes sense to just create a new file for each test you do, organizing them into folder structure as needed:

- baseline.cpp - just main function
- arrays.cpp - using arrays
- classes.cpp - using classes

Configure this project in such a way that you can easily compile/run just one file or all the files at once.

Of course, it is a good idea to keep this entire project in Git and commit each new experiment as you go.

At the end, you will have something like mini-compliance test for the compiler: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/199708/is-there-a-compliance-test-for-c-compilers